# Get-ChildItem file/folder

Tags: powershell

I am trying to let [Get-ChildItem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx) retrieve the contents of a folder, and show the size of each object in the folder, the name and the type of object (file/directory). I am however having trouble getting only those three columns to work.

The name and length are rather straightforward, but how do I display differences between files and folders?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the [PSIsContainer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730953.aspx) property. It is set to $true for folders and $false for files. Here's an example:

```
Get-ChildItem | Foreach-Object{
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Name = $_.Name
        SizeMB = if($_.PSIsContainer) { (Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse | Measure-Object Length -Sum).Sum/1mb  } else {$_.Length}
        Type = if($_.PSIsContainer) {'Directory'} else {'File'}
    }
}
```

Comment: Once again the winning answer. So if I am correct, you create a property object for each object in the folder. And for each property object you assign a name value, a sizevalue and a type value based on the previous value. 

The only thing I dont understand is how you defined the size. I think you use the -recurse switch to measure the whole directory's size, and for files you use the Length? Does Measure-Object not work for files aswell? 

Either way, thanks again!

Comment: A file has a Length property so we don't need anything else but it to know the size. On the other hand folders do not have a Length property. To calculate the folder size we need to iterate over all of its files (recursively) ans sum up the length of all of them. That's where the Measure-Object cmdlet comes handy.

Comment: Nice algorithm, @Shay! However, there is one inconsistency--you are calculating _megabytes_ for directories but just _bytes_ for files. The simplest fix is to change the property name from `SizeMB` to `Size` and delete the divide-by-1mb on the folder size calculation.

Comment: You're absolutely right @msorence, I added MB calculation just to show that it's possible. I'll leave it up to reader to decide if he wants the result in bytes or MB :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe that this is possible by taking the 'Mode' information. ( See this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939802/what-are-the-possible-mode-values-returned-by-powershells-get-childitem-cmdle) )

Basically, then, anything listed by the `Get-ChildItem` command whereby the 'Mode' begins with "`d`".

Here's the actual meanings of the 6 possible values in 'Mode', if you didn't want to go to [@Joey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73070/joey)'s answer:

> In any case, the full list is:
>
> ```
> d - Directory
> a - Archive
> r - Read-only
> h - Hidden
> s - System
> l - Reparse point, symlink, etc.
> ```

So I've used this to output a CSV, which I'll then flag the folders in excel, or my Flow, or SharePoint. The command I've used is:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Select-Object DirectoryName, BaseName, Extension, Mode | Export-Csv -Path INSERTPATH\listings.csv -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation
```

Hope that this helps anyone that comes across it.

---

*Caveat, this is first time that I'm answering with the full intent of answering. I believe that even though this is 6 years old, people will still find it useful when trying to achieve the same thing.*